# How to properly use http.request

Tags: http, lua, request

So I am trying to make an http request to the trello API. I know for sure the URL I am providing is correct I just don't really know how to properly use http.request

I have tried supplying my url and my method to the function. The code shown is not everything. I don't know what else to supply other than method and url

```lua
   local r,c = http.request {
       method = "POST",
       url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards"..GetAddon()..FormData(tab),
   }

   print(r,c)
```

When the request is complete it prints out `1` and `301`

Comment: It's returning `301`, which means that it's `Moved Permanently` and isn't the correct URI to use. Make sure that your `GetAddon()` and `FormData(tab)` functions are working properly. You may consider putting the full URL in a local variable and doublechecking to ensure it's the correct URL and go from there.

Comment: Additionally, you should post the two functions listed so we have an idea of what's going on. Anything that's related to your problem (including the functions) should always be included. You can censor out any personal information, though.

Comment: Where does `http` come from? It's not a standard Lua library.